# Convert URL into hyperlink

Tags: ios, objective-c, hyperlink

I am working on a app in which I am sharing event image with some url
When sharing the event image I am using this content :=

"Hey! I just saw "Venue Name" is having "Event Name" through the XXXX App! We 
should check it out. https://app.com/site/redirectlink?event_id=%@"

Now can I make this "https://app.com/site/redirectlink?event_id=%@" link to hyperlink "here"?

I am sharing this content via "UIActivityViewController". 
Actually this URL (https://app.com/site/redirectlink?event_id=%@) is used for deep linkling later on when user click this it will be redirect to particular event depend on the event_id. 
Instead on the whole URL I want to  use here(as hyperlink) only.

Comment: How do you "share" exactly?

Comment: if you're sharing this content through other apps then it's NO.

Comment: tell us what you need to do please

Comment: @Larme I have edited my question

Comment: @Niharika after the edit you might want to have look at [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) for deep linking or we can say Universal links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might be help you this way..

```
NSString *url=@"https://app.com/site/redirectlink?event_id=%@";
    NSString * title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey! I just saw \"Venue Name\" is having \"Event Name\" through the XXXX App! We should check it out <html> <body> <a href = '%@'>here</a> </body> </html>",url];
    NSArray* dataToShare = @[title];
    UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Comment: Hi. This hyperlink only works with mail. While we share content through SMS it shows url with html tags. any solution for that?

Comment: @Niharika you can send it direct url because SMS does not support HTML or URLs, **its accept just plain text.**
you can write like this way.... ==> 
NSString *title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey! I just saw \"Venue Name\" is having \"Event Name\" through the XXXX App! We should check it out here\n%@",url];

Answer (score 0):

You may want deep linking for url : [projectName://myapp?event_id=12345](http://projectName://myapp?event_id=12345)

Add ***info.plist***

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.erimkurt.projectName</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>projectName</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Add ***appdelegete.m***

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

        NSLog(@"Calling Application Bundle ID: %@", sourceApplication);
        NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);
        NSLog(@"URL query: %@", [url query]);

        return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if (!url) {  return NO; }

    UIAlertView *alertView;
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Launch by URL" message:@"This app was launched from a URL" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:urlString forKey:@"url"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    return YES;
}
```

Add ***viewController.m***

```
NSString *url = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSLog(@"MYAPPURL: %@",url);
```